# How can I render [webform_submission:values] in a table?

Tags: webforms, emails

I am trying to figure out from where [webform_submission:values] gets rendered. This is how it looks right now in the email submission.

```
Label 1
Value 1

Label 2
Value 2
```

I want this in a table format. Is there a possibility to change the render code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Webform tokens from submitted data as following guide:

```
[webform_submission:values:?]
```

> Omit the '?' to output all values. Output all values as HTML using [webform_submission:values:html].
> To output individual elements, replace the '?' with…

```
element_key
element_key:format
element_key:raw
element_key:format:items
element_key:delta
element_key:sub_element_key
element_key:delta:sub_element_key
element_key:sub_element_key:format
element_key:delta:sub_element_key:format
element_key:delta:format
element_key:delta:format:html
element_key:entity:*
element_key:delta:entity:*
element_key:delta:entity:field_name:*
element_key:sub_element_key:entity:*
element_key:sub_element_key:entity:field_name:*
element_key:delta:sub_element_key:entity:*
element_key:checked:option_value
element_key:selected:option_value
```

- All items after the 'element_key' are optional.
- The 'delta' is the numeric index for specific value
- The 'sub_element_key' is a composite element's sub element key.
- The 'checked' or 'selected' looks to see if an 'option_value' is checked or selected for an options element (select, checkboxes, or radios)
- The 'option_value' is options value for an options element (select, checkboxes, or radios).
- The 'format' can be 'value', 'raw', or custom format specifically associated with the element
- The 'items' can be 'comma', 'semicolon', 'and', 'ol', 'ul', or custom delimiter
- The 'entity:*' applies to the referenced entity
- Add 'html' at the end of the token to return HTML markup instead of plain text.

> For example, to display the Contact webform's 'Subject' element's value you would use the [webform_submission:values:subject] token.

Then you can use your custom style by adding them into table or list

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement `hook_tokens_alter` and then use the `[webform_submission:values:html]` token instead.

```
 * Implements hook_tokens_alter().
 */
function onset_cart_tokens_alter(array &$replacements, array $context, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $options = $context['options'];

  if ($context['type'] == 'webform_submission' && !empty($context['data']['webform_submission'])) {
    /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
    $webform_submission = $context['data']['webform_submission'];
    // Now you have access to your webform submission and can retrieve any values. 
    
    // Alter the [webform_submission:values] token.
    if (isset($context['tokens']['values:html'])) {
      $options['html'] = TRUE;
      
      $replacements[$context['tokens']['values:html']] = // call the function to crate a Table element;
    }
  }
}
```